# SSRS dynamic data retrieval from another dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I want to get data(dynamic) according to the data in another dataset and put the result in textbox of the different dataset.

Right now, the data I get is static and I tried to use many expressions but no avail.

Problem lies in editing textbox expression. Since I am getting data from different dataset, it always ask me to have dataset aggregate function in my expression. If I specified the dataset from where I am getting the data, then, I cannot make it dynamic - and I get the undesired result.

And another way out that I attempted is merging the data sets into one rather than having multiples and use it only but this was unsuccessful.

How can I make it work to get the result that I want:

[image: Employee list by department]

By the way, the textbox and the tables are in different scope. I have tried to combine them in one scope too.

Comment: More precise information regarding your inputs and desired output would be helpful

Comment: The department name (X) will be changed automatically.  Let says in first page of my report, I will list down all the IT employees, for the next the employees from Production department and so on…At the same time, the first text box will be changed accordingly. Both of the text box(department) and the employee table are in different dataset.They both are under same company.  How do I make it to change my department ID dynamically?

Comment: [IMG]http://i64.tinypic.com/2a5g3vb.png[/IMG]

Comment: sorry, I am new to SSRS and there are alot I am unsure of.

Comment: If the department and employees are in different tables how do you know which employee is in which department?

Comment: I have same company name/ID in both of the datasets. @Jonnus

Comment: Can you not change the underlying query to return the department name in the dataset with the employee names? That would be simplest, then use a matrix to display your information

Comment: Your alternative is using @Chris Latta's solution below

Comment: Hi Thanks both of your help @Jonnus and Chris.Chris's solution seems very straight forward to me. However, I am still getting dataset aggregate function error. "it says ...the text box directly refers to the field without specifying a dataset aggregate when the report has multiple datasets, field references outside of a data region must be contained with aggregate functions wich specify a dataset scope.

Comment: Update your original question with example datasets and current design - it's difficult to help you further without this information.

Comment: Is the Department Id textbox part of your table or a separate textbox? It looks like what you want to do is simply group the table on Department Id, have a group header and put the field in there. Then the Department Id would be in the same table and so the same scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting data from another dataset requires an aggregate function because it can't tell what data you want from that dataset so it forces you to aggregate it so it can return a specific value rather than an entire list of values.

I think what you are after is the [Lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ee210531.aspx) function. Lookup allows you to look up a value from another dataset based on a value in the table's dataset. To give a simplistic example, let's say your table was of employees and you had a department id on that table and another dataset called "Departments" which had an id and a name. You could look up the department's name using the following expression:

```
=Lookup(Fields!DeptId.Value, Fields!Id.Value, Fields!Name.Value, "Departments")
```

This uses the current table's dataset's `DeptId` field to look up the `Departments` dataset by the `Id` field and return the `Name` field.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Chris. However, I am still getting dataset aggregate error.

Answer (score 0):

```
=Lookup(First(ReportItems!EmpID.Value),Fields!EmpID.Value,Fields!Dept.Value,"dataset_which_u_retrieve_the_data_from")
```

Problem solved!By using reportItems instead of Fields because I am retrieving one data only,not the whole field.

Thanks guys for helping me out.